# VB.NET: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: excel, vb.net

I know this is a common error when trying to pass data to MS Excel, but here is the problem I have encountered

```
Public Sub BackupData()
    Try
        Dim xlaap As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlworksheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misvalue As Object = Reflection.Missing.Value

        xlaap = New Excel.Application
        xlaap.Workbooks.Add()
        xlworksheet = xlaap.Sheets("Sheet1")

        SqlCon.Open()
        SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM profile_tbl", SqlCon)
        SqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
        SqlDataset = New DataSet
        SqlAdapter.Fill(SqlDataset)
        SQLReader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader
        SqlCon.Close()
        'While SQLReader.Read
        For x = 0 To SqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For y = 0 To SqlDataset.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                xlworksheet.Cells(x + 1, y + 1) = SqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item(y)
            Next
        Next
        'End While

        xlworksheet.SaveAs("D:\Reports.xlsx")
        xlaap.Quit()
End Sub
```

The error is in this line: `xlworksheet.Cells(x + 1, y + 1) = SqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item(y)`

When I try to replace *Rows(x)* and *Item(y)* with *Rows(1)* and *Item(1)* to test it out if it will work, it did. Now I am confused, since it doesn't make sense, unless I made a mistake somewhere, but the blasted error message is not helping me at all..

I wanna know why it is showing that error in that line and possibly the solution..

Comment: the line you've said causes the error does not appear anywhere in your actual code sample. Instead you use `xlworksheet.Cells(x + 1, y + 1)`. please confirm the _exact_ circumstances under which it fails. Also on which iterations of the two `For` loops does it fail?

Comment: P.S TBH if you have the choice I wouldn't use COM interop to manipulate an excel worksheet -there are plenty of free libraries available which allow you to interact with the file itself rather than proxying via the Excel application itself. It would be quicker and more reliable.

Comment: If you declare x and y as integers, does something change?

Comment: @Arvo yes sir, it causes an error, when I try too look at it with `Msgbox(SqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item(y))` It is giving me the item inside the database, which is what I needed.. Also, I think the inner `For` loop is the one failing because the application stops at `xlworksheet.Cells(x + 1, y + 1) = SqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows(x).Item(y)` I've updated it..

Comment: @Germain are you sure that `x` and `y` values are inside the cells range? It starts from 1 to 1048576

Comment: @Simo The cell range of the excel sir? Yes sir, I've added +1 to both of them, and still not working..

Comment: @Germain Did you debug your code line by line untill it throws the exception? looking inside any variable used at the moment when it crash?

Comment: I've already done that sir, posting this question here is my last resort..

Comment: @Germain Did you try to change your `SqlDataSet` type from `DataSet` to `DataTable` ? Never had problems with DataTables to copy sql query results on an excel file

Comment: I cannot see how you declared your connection. Are you using `ACE.OLEDB.12`?

Comment: I changed it just now sir, and it gave me the same error..

Comment: I'm using SQL Server sir..

Comment: what are the values of `x` and `y` respectively at the moment the crash happens? We know it fails in the loop, that's obvious...so what we want to know is _which iteration of the loop_ it fails on. Clearly the loop may be executed many times. It would help to know if it fails on a specific time.

Comment: @ADyson sir, the Value of `x` is 0, value of `y` is 11..

Comment: @ADyson I have an _image_ data type in my database at column 11 sir. Is that not allowed? Or is the method of passing the data to excel different?

Comment: Well `image` is binary data, so certainly you cannot simply write that into an Excel cell as if it were a string or number. What would you expect the result to be? Files and/or images in excel are treated as separate embedded objects, they are not associated with a cell.

Comment: @ADyson Okay sir, thank you very much, now I have an idea how to approach this problem. But sir, to clarify, it is not impossible to pass image binary data straight to excel right?

Comment: I don't know for sure, I haven't tried it. But I would expect you can probably embed an object from binary data, yes.

Comment: Okay sir, I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: @Germain you are kind of new here. Take this question as a lesson: If you gave us all the information at the start (like x and y value when it crashes or what's inside your sql table at column 11 for exapmple) this problem would be solved in a second